# Rotate pie chart in interactive window without replotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a pie chart out of provided data, and this can potentially get out of hand as the length of the labels can be pretty long, and there can be a lot of them overlapping each other. Because of this, it is crucial to find a good startangle parameter to my pie chart drawing.

Conceptually, I want to use a mouse scroll event to rotate the whole pie chart by 5 degrees every time the user uses the scroll wheel. Rotating the wedges isn't too much trouble with their theta1 and theta2 properties, but repositioning the labels and autotexts is serious trouble because of alignment properties and the lining up with wedges. I also want to retain an interactive frame rate, so clearing the figure and redrawing is not an option.

Here is one such situation where this is useful. The labels are too big and rotating the whole pie chart would help reposition them in sight. Of course in this case it would be enough to resize the chart instead of rotating but you get my point.

[image: Pie chart with labels going off the side]

Is there a way to achieve this that does not imply rewriting the entire label and autotext positioning code for my own use?

In particular, I'm wondering if it wouldn't be possible to do something that is conceptually equivalent to making the same `pyplot.pie` call as before, only with a different startangle. Alternatively, maybe Text objects have methods I can use for positioning them around the newly rotated wedges that spare me working with just positions and sizes.

Comment: Can you provide code that generates your issue?

Comment: I mean, I suppose I can... it's just putting those numbers and labels that you see in two arrays and then calling pyplot.pie() on them. Nothing else going on